# Issue with website form input field on IOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, wordpress, forms

I'm looking for another set of eyes to take a look at the html and css of this page https://www.smartcrowd.ae/e-book/ on their iphone.

For some reason on Iphones only the form will not allow the user to tap into the phone number field. No matter where you tap in the input field, it will not allow you to type anything.

On safari, on desktop, it works but only if you enter the country code first.

It's working fine on google chrome, and firefox and I just can't find what the issue is.

The form is using a third-party plugin which generates the country code field, which seems to be a problem.  If I deactivate the plugin the phone number input field works fine.

I've been racking my brain for the last day trying to figure this out.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Sorry, the page was cached. I've purged it now, you'll be able to see the issue now.  I'm not able to put the example into the question as it relies on a third party plug-in which is causing the issue. - hope that clears up any confusion.

Comment: Please read my previous comment again.

Comment: Seriously? I can't replicate the problem by presenting a minimal and verifiable example. The problem is only visible on a particular device, and is being caused by either HTML or CSS issues which occur when a third-party plugin enabled. This third party plugin is required for the form to process a certain field.

If i paste the HTML and CSS into a jsfiddle or snippet, it works fine. Because the plugin is not involved.